# Creating links with words in a string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I am storing tags in my database for a specific item using commas.

For example the tags for a person might be.

```
$tags = "tall, fun, cool";
```

I am trying to create each word into a link and remove the comma.

So far I've got,

```
$tags = str_replace(",", "", $tags);
```

I would like the links to be similar to this

```
<a href="#tall>tall</a> <a href="#fun>fun</a>, etc...
```

I'm stuck on the creating a link part though, looking for some help please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach (array_map('trim', explode(',', $tags)) as $tag) {
  echo "<a href=\"#$tag\">$tag</a>";
}
```

1. Split the string at `,` into an array (`explode()`)
2. Remove all leading and trailing whitespaces (`trim()`) from every array element (`array_map()`)
3. Just iterate and output.